# Any one can find the timeout issue in my New Year Chaos solution(even I used index)?

Tags: python, algorithm, timeout

My design is to pop or delete the max value in the list and then add up the difference between the max value index and the length of the list (moves)
I thought it is a pretty cool method and it uses index so should be fast, however, the solution passed the first 3 test cases only and then timed out on the extremely long list. Here is my code:

```py
def minimumBribes(q):
    # Write your code here
    total_moves = 0
    max_value = max(q)
    max_value_index = q.index(max_value)
    while max_value_index != len(q)-1 or len(q)>1:
        if len(q) - 1 - max_value_index >= 3:
            print ("Too chaotic")
            return

        total_moves += (len(q)-1-max_value_index)
        q.pop(max_value_index)
        max_value = max(q)
        max_value_index = q.index(max_value)

    print(total_moves)
    return
```

Anybody gives me a lesson on why this is not fast enough?

Comment: Removing an arbitrary element from a list is a linear operation.

Comment: What is exactly the problem that you want to solve ?